# Lost focus on eventListener

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

Hi everyone im try loop in tags of html and when I press one button need that change the text of h2 ... but i dont know how to do.

this me html

```js
let contenedor = document.querySelector('.container');
let chText = document.querySelector('.change');

contenedor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    console.log(`Nombre: ${this.name} Nombre target: ${e.target.className}`);

    if(e.target.matches('.inicio')){

        changeText(e);
    }
});

function changeText(e){

    //console.log(e.currentTarget)
    chText.innerText = 'text Change';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
     <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
     <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use querySelectorAll to class change, try loop but this change all text.. and i want to do that only change text the button I press

how to referece between button and text (h2)..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling)... You have to start from the `e.target` to know which `h2` to change.

```js
let contenedor = document.querySelector('.container');

// Don't define it here. That's the first one only, anyway.
//let chText = document.querySelector('.change');  

contenedor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  console.log(`Nombre: ${this.name} Nombre target: ${e.target.className}`);

  if (e.target.matches('.inicio')) {
    changeText(e);
  }
});

function changeText(e) {

  //console.log(e.currentTarget)
  //chText.innerText = 'text Change';
  e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = 'text Change';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you are to have some other elements between th `h2` and the `button`, you will have to look for the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) parent `.card` and then look for the element to change the text...

```js
let contenedor = document.querySelector('.container');

// Don't define it here. That's the first one only, anyway.
//let chText = document.querySelector('.change');  

contenedor.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  console.log(`Nombre: ${this.name} Nombre target: ${e.target.className}`);

  if (e.target.matches('.inicio')) {
    changeText(e);
  }
});

function changeText(e) {
  e.target.closest(".card").querySelector(".change").innerText = 'text Change';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <p>Something else...</p>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <p>Something else...</p>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="border:1px solid gray; width: 20%">
      <h2 class="change">HIHO</h2>
      <p>Something else...</p>
      <button class="inicio">Change</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thnz very much yeas I needed the second option, other elements between button or h2.

thnz Louys.